# Quantum well in confining structure

Tags: solid-state-physics, electronic-band-theory

I was studying the confining of electrons in a composite crystal. I don't understand how the fact that the band gaps of the two materials are different translates immediately to the statement that spatially we have a potential well. The bands are calculated in momentum space not in real space that's the main point of my doubt.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Those $E$ vs $k$ bands for a given material are only valid in the space that material occupies.

Comment: Yes that's true but what tells me that the resulting wave function will be localized in space?

Comment: The fact that there is a band offset that results in a potential that confines a region in space localizes the wave function.